# Where to get Review articles?

Tags: publications, review-articles

I am wondering about review articles. Where to get them? Google scholar or Researchgate or other such sites does not provide any option to separate out the review articles. It is very hard to look into all the articles and separate out.

Is there any way to separate out the review articles only?

Comment: Web of Science lets you filter search results according to document types, which includes the option "REVIEW".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for biomedical reviews, [Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) allows you to filter reviews after searching for keywords. This option is available in the sidebar, under "Article Types". Depending on your field, there might be other search engines that allow this type of filtering.

On Google Scholar, you can refine your searches by using Google search operators. For example, if you search for *insubject:"obstructive lung disease" intext:"review"*, Google Scholar will return results that have "Obstructive Lung Disease" in the title and the word "review" somewhere in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your field, there may also be journals dedicated to reviews. For example, sociology has the "Annual Review of Sociology." Check out http://www.annualreviews.org to see if your field has a journal. There is also a handy search bar where you can search for a topic within a journal.

This does not, of course, get you a comprehensive set of review articles on a topic, but if you're just looking for a starting place to learn about a topic it could be helpful.